# How to create the given jSON format from a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, json, pandas, csv, dictionary

> The data looks like this :

[image]

> The expected Json fomat is like this

```
    {
    "DataExtractName": "SalesDataExtract",
    "BusinessName" : {
        "InvoiceDate": {
            "SourceSystem": {
                "MYSQL" : "Invc_Dt",
                "CSV" : "Invc_Date"
            },
            "DataType": {
                "MYSQL" : "varchar",
                "CSV" : "string"
            }
        },
        "Description": {
            "SourceSystem": {
                "MYSQL" : "Prod_Desc",
                "CSV" : "Prod_Descr"
            },
            "DataType": {
                "MYSQL" : "varchar",
                "CSV" : "string"
            }
        }
    }
},
{
    "DataExtractName": "DateDataExtract",
    "BusinessName" : {
        "InvoiceDate": {
            "SourceSystem": {
                "MYSQL" : "Date"
            },
            "DataType": {
                "MYSQL" : "varchar"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How do i achieve this using python dataframes? Or do i need to write some script to make the data like this?

**Note**

I've tried using -

1. df.to_json
2. df.to_dict

Comment: df.to_json should work, i guess

Comment: @JuhilSomaiya It does works, but I have no clue as to have to get the required JSON Format. The required format is a dict within dict

Comment: Then you must have to write an extra scripts that populates the data in the desired format, i'm not sure though.

Comment: @JuhilSomaiya Do u have anything in mind of that sort?

Comment: kindly share data not pics

Comment: In the JSON, you once refer to `SourceSystem` (as per the table), but elsewhere you refer to `SourceSystemType`. Also, what happens to the last line in the table? There seem to be two entries with `BusinessName = "InvoiceDate"` and `SourceSystem="MySQL"`, but only shows up in the JSON.

Comment: @KenHBS Sorry for those typo's, I've made the necessary changes now. And for the second entry if you can see the DataExtractName is different so it become another entry below.

Answer (score 2):

With so many nested structures, you should use marshmallow. It is built with your use case in mind. Please check out the excellent documentation: https://marshmallow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ . All you need is the masic usage.

It is a lot of code, but better be explicit than clever. I am sure a shorter solution exists, but it is probably unmaintainable. Also I had to build your dataframe. Please provide it in a data format next time.

```
import pandas as pd
import marshmallow as ma

# build test data
df = pd.DataFrame.from_records([
                               ['InvoiceDate', 'MYSQL', 'Invc_Dt', 'varchar', 'SalesDataExtract'],
                               ['InvoiceDate', 'CSV', 'Invc_Date', 'string', 'SalesDataExtract'], 
                               ['Description', 'MYSQL', 'Prod_Descr', 'varchar', 'SalesDataExtract'],
                               ['Description', 'CSV', 'Prod_Descr', 'string', 'SalesDataExtract'],
                               ['InvoiceDate', 'MYSQL', 'Date', 'varchar', 'DateDataExtract'],]
                        )
df.columns = ['BusinessName', 'SourceSystem', 'FunctionalName', 'DataType', 'DataExtractName']


# define marshmallow schemas
class SourceSystemTypeSchema(ma.Schema):
    MYSQL = ma.fields.String()
    CSV = ma.fields.String()

class DataTypeSchema(ma.Schema):
    MYSQL = ma.fields.String()
    CSV = ma.fields.String()

class InvoiceDateSchema(ma.Schema):
    InvoiceDate = ma.fields.Nested(SourceSystemTypeSchema())
    DataType = ma.fields.Nested(DataTypeSchema())

class DescriptionSchema(ma.Schema):
    SourceSystem = ma.fields.Nested(SourceSystemTypeSchema())
    DataType = ma.fields.Nested(DataTypeSchema())

class BusinessNameSchema(ma.Schema):
    InvoiceDate = ma.fields.Nested(InvoiceDateSchema())
    Description = ma.fields.Nested(DescriptionSchema())

class DataSchema(ma.Schema):
    DataExtractName = ma.fields.String()
    BusinessName = ma.fields.Nested(BusinessNameSchema())

# building json
result = []

mask_business_name_invoicedate = df.BusinessName == 'InvoiceDate'
mask_business_name_description = df.BusinessName == 'Description'

for data_extract_name in set(df['DataExtractName'].to_list()):
    mask_data_extract_name = df.DataExtractName == data_extract_name

    # you need these two helper dfs to get the dictionaries 
    df_source_system = df[mask_data_extract_name & mask_business_name_invoicedate].set_index('SourceSystem').to_dict(orient='dict')
    df_description = df[mask_data_extract_name & mask_business_name_description].set_index('SourceSystem').to_dict(orient='dict')

    # all dictionaries are defined, so you can use your schemas
    source_system_type = SourceSystemTypeSchema().dump(df_source_system['FunctionalName'])
    data_type = DataTypeSchema().dump(df_source_system['DataType'])
    source_system = SourceSystemTypeSchema().dump(df_description['FunctionalName'])
    invoice_date = InvoiceDateSchema().dump({'SourceSystemType': source_system_type, 'DataType': data_type})
    description = DescriptionSchema().dump({'SourceSystem': source_system, 'DataType': data_type})
    business_name = BusinessNameSchema().dump({'InvoiceDate': invoice_date, 'Description': description})
    data = DataSchema().dump({'DataExtractName': data_extract_name, 'BusinessName': business_name})

    # end result
    result.append(data)
```

Now,

```
ma.pprint(result)
```

returns

```
[{'BusinessName': {'Description': {'DataType': {'CSV': 'string',
                                                'MYSQL': 'varchar'},
                                   'SourceSystem': {'CSV': 'Prod_Descr',
                                                    'MYSQL': 'Prod_Descr'}},
                   'InvoiceDate': {'DataType': {'CSV': 'string',
                                                'MYSQL': 'varchar'}}},
  'DataExtractName': 'SalesDataExtract'},
 {'BusinessName': {'Description': {'DataType': {'MYSQL': 'varchar'},
                                   'SourceSystem': {}},
                   'InvoiceDate': {'DataType': {'MYSQL': 'varchar'}}},
  'DataExtractName': 'DateDataExtract'}]
```

Comment: As you said, I'm also pretty sure there is an easier way to do this. Anyway, I like this thorough answer! +1